# How to pass Password to password protected pdf file programmatically?

Tags: c#, jquery, pdf, plugins, passwords

How to pass Password to password protected pdf file progrmatically in MVC or jquery? 
**Is there any plugin or a way to pass Password to password protected pdf file progrmatically?**

**Scenario** :
I want that if user login in to application then the current user's password will be the password of the protected pdf file.so, when user view the protected pdf in browser then how to pass password progrmatically from getting password from current session?

Comment: or How to display PDF on webpage or make it able to view on webpage or on browser with preventing it to download?in Asp.Net MVC. is there any way or plugin is available for this?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent from downloading, you will need to use images for all the pdf pages instead. Display these images using html pages. Users can still take screenshot of the images so add watermarks to the pdf pages as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.but how to prevent user from download the image? have you any reference link or some reference code?please share.

Answer (score 0):

you can use PyPDF library in Python to password protect a PDF file.